# How can I get the most Memory Prisms as fast as possible from the Magitek Facility (Celes) event?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

The new Celes event has some pretty steep thresholds for rewards! The top end, a 5* Holy Orb, requires a whopping **200,000 Memories**!

Since the number of memories per fight doesn't seem to be fixed, is there a way to get more of them faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YES!**

The fights you'll encounter during this "Survival" event *are* randomly generated, however, they are generated *all at once* on entering the dungeon, and there are a set number of 'paths' or sequences of monsters encountered. Since you can see what enemy you'll be facing *before* entering a fight, you can make use of the **Retreat** button before engaging anything to force the game to reset the path and generate a new random seed.

When running the event on **Hard** (which yields the highest Memories/Stamina, *natch*), you'll want to reset the dungeon until the first monster generated is **Number 024**; doing this will guarantee you one of two paths, which will result in either **4234** or **5084** stones per clear, which are the two highest yield outcomes possible.

[image: Stage 1 Screenshot]

If you're not quite up to handling Hard mode (and keep in mind that the path beginning with Number 024 on Hard is a touch more difficult - his constantly shifting barriers can be troublesome), then you can apply the same technique on normal mode. However, **on Normal, you'll want to reset until you see *Number 128*** for best results.

In both cases, keep in mind that these are somewhat rare seeds; you may need to reset the dungeon many times before you see what you're looking for. But your patience will be rewarded, so long as you're Stamina isn't capping out while you chain reset.

If for some reason, you're more interested in maximizing XP than Stamina, you can use this same method, but rather than resetting for Number 024, you should keep an eye out for the Jelly on Hard; you'll fight five of them, which can be one-shot by most AoE spells that aren't Quake; you'll get 15,000 XP, split amongst party members, before Synergy. If you take a level 1 Celes in alone with Aeris or Rydia and a summon spell, or any melee heavy hitter that has Bladeblitz, she'll instantly jump to level 13, for example. (Don't bother completing the dungeon if this is your goal though, retreat after the first fight, and then repeat.)

Comment: FWIW, here are the sequences I've seen and the memory prism totals that go with them: Number 024 - 5080 if floor 5 is Number 128, 4234 otherwise. Ifrit and Shiva - 4838 if floor 6 is Proto Armor, 2258 otherwise. Flans - 1897 (only seen one sequence so far)

Comment: Had an error in my rounding formula for above comment: Number 024 - 5084 if floor 5 is Number 128, 4234 otherwise. Ifrit and Shiva - 4854 if floor 6 is Proto Armor, 2265 otherwise. Flans - 1910 (only seen one sequence so far)